# Error ocurred when using tf.reduce_mean to compute the mean value of image

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I tried to use tf.reduce_mean to compute the mean value of image for all axes, it showed that "An error ocurred while starting the kernel".

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
imgdata = tf.read_file("./test_img/00000001.jpg")
my_img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(imgdata)
image = tf.reduce_mean(my_img)
tf.Session().run(image)
```

I tried to run session to get "my_img" before computing mean, it didn't work as well.

If I try to compute mean value of an array created by myself with the same shape, it goes well.

```
my_array = = np.random.randn(720, 1280, 3)
tf.Session().run(tf.reduce_mean(my_array))
```

Comment: And the console(Spyder) shows:
"An error ocurred while starting the kernel"  and lots of details about CPU/GPU device and instruction.

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved by converting the data type from uint8 to float32:

```
my_img = 255.0 * tf.image.convert_image_dtype(my_img, tf.float32)
```